# Moving a control within another control's visible area

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, controls, mouseevent

I have a `PictureBox` that is inside a `TabPage`, and of course this `TabPage` is part of a `TabView` and this `TabView` is inside a `Form`. I want users be able to move this picture box within the tab page. For this I am using the `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseUp` events of the picture box:

```
private void pictureBoxPackageView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_mapPackageIsMoving)
    {
        _mapPackageIsMoving = true;
    }
} 

private void pictureBoxPackageView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(_mapPackageIsMoving)
    {
        pictureBoxPackageView.Location = MousePosition; //This is not exact at all!
        return;
    }

    //Some other code for some other stuff when picturebox is not moving...
}

private void pictureBoxPackageView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_mapPackageIsMoving)
    {
        _mapPackageIsMoving = false; //Mouse button is up, end moving!
        return;
    }
}
```

But my problem lies in the `MouseMove` event. As soon as I move mouse after button down, the picture box jumps out of tab page's visible area.

I need to know how to handle the move only within the rectangle of the tab page, and if picture box is being dragged out of tab view's visible area, it shouldn't move anymore unless user brings the mouse inside the tab view's visible rectangle.

Any helps/tips will be appriciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a variable to hold the original position of the PictureBox:

Modified from a [HansPassant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9805776/719186):

```
private Point start = Point.Empty;

void pictureBoxPackageView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  _mapPackageIsMoving = false;
}

void pictureBoxPackageView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (_mapPackageIsMoving) {
    pictureBoxPackageView.Location = new Point(
                             pictureBoxPackageView.Left + (e.X - start.X), 
                             pictureBoxPackageView.Top + (e.Y - start.Y));
  }
}

void pictureBoxPackageView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  start = e.Location;
  _mapPackageIsMoving = true;
}
```