# Preventing moving of a control out of its container

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, mouseevent, mousemove

This question is related to another question of mine which can be found here [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994530/moving-a-control-within-another-controls-visible-area). I wanted to move a `PictureBox` within its parent container which is a `TabPage` (If it does make any difference!) Using the code below the movement can be done:

```
private Point start = Point.Empty; 
private bool _mapPackageIsMoving;    

void pictureBoxPackageView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { 
  _mapPackageIsMoving = false; 
} 

void pictureBoxPackageView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { 
  if (_mapPackageIsMoving) { 
    pictureBoxPackageView.Location = new Point( 
                             pictureBoxPackageView.Left + (e.X - start.X),  
                             pictureBoxPackageView.Top + (e.Y - start.Y)); 
  } 
} 

void pictureBoxPackageView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { 
  start = e.Location; 
  _mapPackageIsMoving = true; 
}
```

Now my problem is, There is no limit to this moving of control. User can drag the controls kilometers away from the visible area of the `TabPage` which my picturebox is inside it. I tried to add some limits for movement by changing the `MouseMove` event like this, to atleast prevent it from going out of the `Left` and `Right` visible area of the tabpage:

```
void pictureBoxPackageView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { 
  if (_mapPackageIsMoving) { 
   //Added condition
  if (pictureBoxPackageView.Left >= 0 && pictureBoxPackageView.Right >= 0)
    pictureBoxPackageView.Location = new Point( 
                             pictureBoxPackageView.Left + (e.X - start.X),  
                             pictureBoxPackageView.Top + (e.Y - start.Y)); 
  } 
}
```

But the problem with the code above is whenever the picturebox hits the right or left side of the container and the `Left` or `Right` get equal to 0, I can not move the control anymore.

Any helps/tips to achive limiting this movement inside the container for `Left, Right, Top and Bottom` of the picture box will be appriciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can move the box unconditionally (no testing of the current location) and have a limitation for your new location:

```
int nx = Math.Min(Math.Max(pictureBoxPackageView.Left + (e.X -start.X),0),pictureBoxPackageView.Parent.Width-pictureBoxPackageView.Width);
int ny = Math.Min(Math.Max(pictureBoxPackageView.Top + (e.Y -start.Y),0),pictureBoxPackageView.Parent.Height-pictureBoxPackageView.Height);

pictureBoxPackageView.Location = new Point(nx,ny);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm. Would you mind telling me one more thing? How can I let the control move through the `Bottom` of the container? I mean limit shouldnt apply for Bottom but still apply to left, right and top.

Comment: Never mind, found it as `var y = Math.Min(Math.Max(finalLocation.Y, 0), pictureBoxPackageView.Bottom);`

Comment: there are typo here..
`pictureBoxPackageView.parent` should be `pictureBoxPackageView.Parent`

Answer (score -2):

I think if you add the following code, it will move the item without snapping to the top as an option.

```
//- MouseDownLocation.X
 //- MouseDownLocation.Y 

       int nx = Math.Min(Math.Max(label1.Left - MouseDownLocation.X + (e.X - start.X), 0), label1.Parent.Width - label1.Width);
       int ny = Math.Min(Math.Max(label1.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y + (e.Y - start.Y), 0), label1.Parent.Height - label1.Height);
```

Comment: Why you repeat an answer to a very old topic? Here for some quick points?!

Comment: I think we are bit over-sensitive much. I don't know anything about points and wasn't aware that being helpful was a game. Is this some sort of game that I'm not aware of? I was just trying to be helpful. But that may explain why everyone seems so eager to not help. Lol I would ask a question and get negative points. Is this a gaming site??